# Windows Registry doesn't save changes after reboot

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry, autologin

I'm using a batch script to activate Auto logon on a computer that's a member of doamin.

```
@echo off
REM Set variables
set /p username= What is the username?
set /p domain= What is the domain name?
set /p password= What is the password?

REM Enable Auto Logon
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v AutoAdminLogon /t REG_SZ /d 1

REM Set Username for logon
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultUserName /t REG_SZ /d %username%

REM Set Domain
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultDomainName /t REG_SZ /d %domain%

REM Set Password
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultPassword /t REG_SZ /d %password%

REM Set number of times to auto logon (0 for infinite)
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v AutoLogonCount /t REG_DWORD /d 0
```

Everything works fine after I execute the script, but once I reboot the computer I noticed that the DefaultPassword and AutoAdminLogon values are not saving. I changed the permission but still no luck.

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading the documentation correctly, AutoLogonCount decrements each time the system is automatically logged on, and when it reaches 0 then the auto logon is disabled. It sounds like you are configuring it to immediately end logging in automatically. Try not using the AutoLogonCount value at all (or remove it if it exists). I've never used it before and auto logon works forever without it.

Comment: Ok I will try it. Any ideas why the values won't save after the reboot ?

Comment: I think it's deleting those on the reboot because the value of the count is zero.

Comment: I figured that for the script to work, I have to run it twice... I'm not sure why it's doing that??? Is there a way to fix this ?